# Closing an unbuffered MySQL query after PDO::exec()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To put it short: is there a way to close/flush/etc an unbuffered query made with PDO::exec()?

To give an example in code:

```
abstract class baseTask {

    private $connection = false;

    protected function save($data) {
        if (!$this->connection) $this->connect();
        /*
        $this->tables() here returns the tables & fields a child class uses
        */
        foreach ($this->tables() as $table => $fields) {
            $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table';";
            if($this->connection->exec($sql) === 0) {
                $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (";
                $prefix = "";
                foreach ($fields as $name => $opts) {
                    $sql .= "$prefix$name $opts";
                    $prefix = ", ";
                }
                $sql .= ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
                if ($this->connection->exec($sql) == 0) {
                    var_dump($this->connection->errorInfo());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function connect() {
        $config = $this->config();
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$config['database'].";host=".$config['address'].";", $config['username'], $config['password'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
    }

    private function config() {
        return array(
          /* Config */
        );        
    }    
}
```

The objective here is to create tables that don't exist yet, but apparently the "SHOW TABLES" query stays active after it's been evaluated, and PDO can't run the second exec() at all.

The error messages suggests:

> Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll()

but clearly that's not very handy in this situation. How would I finish the first query, so there will be no more active queries once the second query is executed?

**Note:** I am aware that there are ways to work around this problem, but I'd rather actually learn what's going wrong here, what exactly is the use of exec() if not this, and if there's a more elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: You're looking for [closeCursor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php)

Comment: @PatrickQ Not really, as far as I understand. There's no closeCursor() method in PDO, and I don't have a PDOStatement to closeCursor() with.

Comment: What about using `query()` instead of `exec()`? That will return a `PDOStatement` object.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you even interested in the result of the `SHOW TABLES LIKE…` query when you are doing a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`? The `IF NOT EXISTS` part makes your previous check rather pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, `if($this->connection->exec($sql) === 0)` is not a good idea.

From PHP.net :

> "PDO::exec() does not return results from a SELECT statement. For a SELECT statement that you only need to issue once during your program, consider issuing PDO::query()."

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

Change it and tell us if it solve the problem.

Comment: I can work around using exec, but then again I'm not really looking for a result set in this case, but exactly what exec returns:
"PDO::exec() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the number of rows affected by the statement."
So shouldn't my usecase be something exec is specifically meant for?

Comment: @Klasu Not really.  `PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0.` Your first query is neither modifying nor deleting any rows.

Comment: true, a select query sent via exec will always return 0, the test is useless.

Comment: You are doing exactly what is described in my quote

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong to assume exec would work with SHOW TABLES. I changed it to:
$stmt = $this->connection->query($sql);
if(empty($stmt->fetchAll())) { ...
and that fixes the problem. Thanks to you both!